# JQuery replaceWith problem

Tags: jquery, replacewith

I'm replacing a DOM node with HTML returned from an AJAX call.  The returned HTML has an id and the DOM node with that id is to be replaced.

The callback function

```
function updateTrip(xml, success, jqXHR) {
  var para = $(xml);  
  var id = para.attr('id');
  $("#"+id).replaceWith(para);  
}
```

fails to replace the node although the same code with a fixed id works, and the equivalent raw JavaScript function also works

```
function updateTrip(xml, success, jqXHR) {
  var para = $(xml).get(0);  
  var id = para.getAttribute('id');
  var div = document.getElementById(id);
  div.parentNode.replaceChild(para, div);
```

}

The ids look like n-1.12.2.2.4 ; the content-type is text/html; no errors reported in the FF error console.

Comment: Have you tried changing that last line to  $("#"+id).replaceWith(xml); ?

Comment: var id = para.attr('id'); alert(id) -> shows the correct one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the `.` in your id, you need to escape the `.` for the selector to work correctly.

Example:

`$("#n-1\\.12\\.2\\.2\\.4")`

With that being said, the easiest option would be to use `document.getElementById()` and simply use `.replaceWith()`

```
function updateTrip(xml, success, jqXHR) {
  var para = $(xml);  
  var id = para.attr('id');
  var a = document.getElementById(id);
  $(a).replaceWith(para);  
}
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/L88xC/)**

or if you want to do the `replace()` option it would look like this:

```
function updateTrip(xml, success, jqXHR) {
    var para = $(xml);
    var id = para.attr('id').replace(/\./g, '\\.');
    $('#' + id).replaceWith(para);
}
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/L88xC/1/)**

Comment: It's advisable to steer clear of periods in IDs, even though they are permitted, it causes havoc in sizzle and other selector libraries.  [This post explains nicely.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html/72577#72577)

Comment: Thanks both for the answers - the more minimal javascript version works fine but I'll have to consider recoding ids